# Cannot install Docker Compose v2: "Invalid Plugin, exec format error"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I installed the new `docker compose` CLI according to the instructions on [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#install-on-linux) (Ubuntu 20.04) and cannot use the plugin.

The command `docker compose help` shows:

```
$ docker compose help
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

When running `docker help`, I get:

```
$ docker help

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

[[ OMMITTED NORMAL OUTPUT ]]

Invalid Plugins:
  compose     failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /home/myname/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose: exec format error

Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.

To get more help with docker, check out our guides at https://docs.docker.com/go/guides/
```

Same when installing under `/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins` and running the command as root.

I currently use `docker` version 20.10.7 and `docker-compose` version 1.28.0.

What am I doing wrong? How to get the new `compose` to work?

Comment: The error message has a plugin filename and `exec format error`; what kind of file exactly is the plugin?  Do you need to decompress it, or unpack a tar file, or something else?

Comment: @DavidMaze it is a binary file that gets downloaded from https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.0.0 -- according to the docs on the linked website, no unpacking is needed, only `chmod +x`

Comment: Have you checked?  `file ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose`?

Comment: @DavidMaze :o you're right: the link is wrong, no asset with this name exists in release 2.0.0! Was fixed in 2.0.1 apparently... I wrongly assumed that `curl` would crash if the link was invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is solved with **version 2.0.1** instead of 2.0.0

Until the docs get updated, just change the cURL command to download the newer version:

```sh
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.0.1/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

The cause is a missing asset in the Github Release.

Works like a charm:

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.0.1
```

**EDIT**: as of October 26th 2021, the documentation has been updated to link to the correct download-artifact. This answer remains valid for the case when artifacts are missing, which may happen with future versions or other plugins.